# Dual boot with Linux after deletion: grub rescue

Tags: grub2

I dual booted my computer which originally had Windows 7 installed on it, with Backtrack 5 R3. I went through the install process perfectly and BT was working very well.

I then restarted my system and booted up into Windows. I went into disk management, because I was curious about what partition BT was installed on, and *by mistake I deleted the partition* that it was installed on.

I thought there was nothing on this partition and was really stupid not to check how much space had been used on the drive. Anyways, I restarted my computer and came up to the screen that says:

```
"error: unknown file system Grub rescue>!!!!!!
```

This is EASY to fix, I had it once before with Linux Mint. I just repaired the boot loader with my Windows 7 Recovery Disk. However, this time it is not as simple. I cant boot into ANY CDs/DVDs, including my Windows 7 disk and backtrack, even though my first boot device is set to Internal CD ROM.

The problem is that when I boot up my computer, I cannot access my BIOS. No onscreen keys r shown (the usual <kbd>F2</kbd> on my LG laptop). I have tried all key combinations incase it had switched my BIOS key, which is very unlikely, but it was worth a shot. It just takes me straight to the GRUB rescue prompt where I can virtually do nothing. I,ve tried LS at the rescue and tried to boot up into one of the hard disks, help commands and any other obvious commands that I thought might work, but nothing!

I cant remember off-hand all the model numbers, but my laptop is an LG , as I mentioned above and have a Toshiba HDD.

Anything else you need to know ?

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a laptop can boot a little too quickly to let you into the BIOS. As you say you know the typical key for your laptop, give this a try:

1. Turn off your laptop.
2. Disconnect the mains power connection to your laptop.
3. Remove the battery (if possible) from your laptop.
4. Give it a minute, then plug the battery back in.
5. Switch on the laptop and immediately keep pressing F2 to see if it lets you in.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I died it with great hopes that it would work, but still the same old problem! 1 thing I forgot to mention in my question is that ive tried taking out my RAM and HDD, removing battery, power cable etc